# Creating a Static Characteristic with Swift and CoreBluetooth

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I'm using Swift 2.2.1 to build an iOS app that functions as a bluetooth peripheral device.

I want to advertise a person's first name as a **static** characteristic, so I'm creating the characteristic like this:

```
    // Build the NAME characteristic
if (identity.name != nil) {
    nameCharacteristic =
        CBMutableCharacteristic(type: performerNameCharacteristicUUID,
            properties: ([CBCharacteristicProperties.Read, CBCharacteristicProperties.Broadcast]),
            value: myIdentity?.name?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding,
                allowLossyConversion: false),
            permissions: CBAttributePermissions.Readable)

    characteristicsArray.append(nameCharacteristic!)
}
```

When the program runs *addServices* is called and this exception pops up:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Characteristics with cached values must be read-only'

Thoughts on what I might be doing wrong would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `CBCharacteristicProperties.Broadcast` property with characteristics you create yourself.  From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCharacteristic_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CBCharacteristicProperties):

> - **CBCharacteristicPropertyBroadcast** The characteristic’s value can be broadcast using a characteristic configuration descriptor.
>
>   This property is not allowed for local characteristics published via
>     the `addService:` method of the `CBPeripheralManager` class. This means
>     that you cannot use this property when you initialize a new
>     `CBMutableCharacteristic` object via the
>     `initWithType:properties:value:permissions:` method of the
>     `CBMutableCharacteristic` class.

Comment: Fixed - thank you! I'd pulled that in a previous version and inadvertently reintroduced it - thanks so much for the help!